# Is it possible to use two HTTPS GitHub accounts on the same mac and switch between them in the terminal without having to delete keychain every time?

Tags: git, github

I have two GitHub accounts. In Mac terminal I work with repos from both GitHub accounts. Every time I switch from a repo from GitHub A to B, I must go to my keychains and delete the authentication, so that it will ask me for the username and token again. I'm using https. There must be a better way!

If I don't do that, then of course I get:

```
$ git push
remote: Permission to hellothere/MyHelloRepo.git denied to myUsername
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/hellothere/MyHelloRepo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: "There must be a better way!" Don't worry, there is. I have two independent GitHub accounts, each with its own private repos, and I work with repos from both accounts, seamlessly, all day long, using Git in the Terminal. But of course if I go to GitHub itself, in the browser, I have to log out and in if I need to change users.

Comment: You just forgot to say how you do that with https

Comment: GitHub no longer supports https username/password authentication. I use SSH. Perhaps that is the first step on your Better Way.

Comment: how you reached "push" for a specific repo in the terminal? means how you are connecting to https repos to start with to have sessions. Looks like SSH is better way to manage this.

Comment: Do you mean that you have AccountA for RepoA and AccountB for RepoB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `keychains` as the credential helper. To specify a username for a network authentication by the repository URL,

```
# Match the full URL instead of only the host
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true

# Specify username1 for the repository https://github.com/hello/world.git
git config --global credential."https://github.com/hello/world.git".username username1

# Specify username2 for the repository https://github.com/hi/ya.git
git config --global credential."https://github.com/hi/ya.git".username username2

# Invoke the authentication to store the username and password/token in the credential helper.
# The ending .git does not matter
git ls-remote https://github.com/hello/world
git ls-remote https://github.com/hi/ya.git
# Enter the password/token
# As Github does not support passwords now, you need to always input a token instead
```

The credential helper now knows which username to use if it's not specified. If you specify a 3rd username, the configured usernames will be ignored.

```
git ls-remote https://username3@github.com/hello/world
```

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to your `~/.ssh` folder, edit your `config` file to something like

```
#user1 account
Host github.com-user1
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user1
   IdentitiesOnly yes

#user2 account
Host github.com-user2
   HostName github.com
   User git
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github-user2
   IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Inspired from https://gist.github.com/Jonalogy/54091c98946cfe4f8cdab2bea79430f9

Comment: Yeah, but that's using SSH and not HTTPS

Comment: You forgot to mention how you have to change the remote url so it actually makes use of the correct setting. That is kinda important. Example, if you after `Host` call it `myPrivateGithub` then the remote url should replace `git@github.com:` with `git@myPrivateGithub:` (if I remember correctly anyway)